# How to define quantity of real roots?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, real-numbers

I have got $x^8-x^5+x^3-1$ and I have to know how many real roots there is. 
Thank you!

Comment: Note that $x^8-x^5+x^3-1=(x^3-1)(x^5+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Just factor from $x^5$ from the first two elements!
$$x^5(x^3-1) + (x^3-1)$$
And now, factor from $x^3 - 1$, you will have:
$$(x^3 - 1)(x^5 + 1)$$

Hence, $x \in \{ 1, -1 \}$ is the result.

Answer (score 0):

By [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs), since there are three sign changes in the given polynomial, there are either $3$ or $1$ positive real roots.  By inspection, $0$ is not a root.  Replacing $x$ by $-x$, there is one sign change, so there is one negative real root.

As argued by others, the negative real root is $-1$, coming from the $x^5 + 1$ factor.  Since that factor has no sign changes, it provides no positive real roots.  The $x^3 -1$ factor has one sign change, so supplies one positive real root, at $1$.  Having exhausted the factors, we have found both real roots and determined that there are no additional positive real roots.

Answer (score -1):

You have $$x^8-x^5+x^3-1=x^5(x^3-1)+x^3-1=(x^5+1)(x^3-1)$$ 
So $x^8-x^5+x^3-1=0\iff x^3=1$ or $x^5=-1\iff x=\pm 1$ the polinomial has only the two real roots $\pm 1$.

Comment: At least to me, it's easier to leave it as $(x^5+1)(x^3-1)$.  Then it is clear that the eight roots are the cube roots of $1$ and the fifth roots of $-1$ and DeMoivre quickly tells us that all but $1$ and $-1$ are complex.